# SQL Select 2 LIKEs

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I need this query to select all posts where category = logotypes and full_text is LIKE the searchword just like it already does.

```
SELECT      *
FROM        posts
WHERE       category = :logotypes
AND         full_text LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
ORDER BY    post_date DESC
```

But I want the searchword to also check if any matches were done in heading like:

```
    SELECT      *
    FROM        posts
    WHERE       category = :logotypes
    AND         full_text LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
--> ALSO CHECK  heading LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
    ORDER BY    post_date DESC
```

How do I do?

P.S the category should always remain. It have to still be `category = :logotypes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace `ALSO CHECK` by `OR`:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        posts
WHERE       category = :logotypes
AND        (full_text LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
OR          heading LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%'))
ORDER BY    post_date DESC
```

Observe the parentheses around the `OR`-connected predicate

Comment: will it only look up where the `category = :logotypes then`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        posts 
WHERE       category = :logotypes 
AND        
(
    full_text LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%') 
    OR 
    heading LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')  
)
ORDER BY    post_date DESC
```

or, if you're feeling obscure

```
AND CONCAT(full_text,'/', heading) LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
```